# how access DevExpress XtraGrid Column CheckEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

One of the Xtragrid columns is CheckEdit(RepositoryItem). On click of add button I need to copy/export all the rows for which the checkedit is checked into an arraylist.

Anyone has any idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the column bound or unbound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I remember well you can use the method GetCellValue, so just loop an all rows and call this method to see if the checkedit was checked, probably GetCellValue will return true in those cases.